# Laptop suddenly overheating and shutting down

Tags: shutdown, fan, overheating, temperature

This is my first time asking a question here, so let me know if you need more information.

TL;DR:

1. Why doesn't my fan show up in pwmconfig?
2. Why is my computer overheating on specific programs?
3. This is either a software issue or a ventilation issue, not a thermal paste issue, because it started suddenly a month ago.

A month ago, my Ubuntu laptop suddenly began randomly shutting down while I was doing various work. It took me a while to figure out why, but I'm 90% sure it's an overheating issue.

Usually it happens after I've been using it for a while, maybe 2 hours or so, but sometimes specific programs make it happen right away.

For example, the appimage I have for Arduino IDE causes an overheat within about ten seconds after launch. I've installed lm-sensors which tells me the temperature, and I've watched it go from 40C to 70C in a matter of seconds, at which point the whole system shuts down. The fan doesn't seem to speed up much while the temperature is spiking.

This wasn't happening before a month ago. I've been using that program for months with no issue, and suddenly it's completely inoperable.

I tried doing the following to check the fan:

1. `sudo sensors-detect` (I went through the whole process
2. `sudo service kmod start`
3. `sudo pwmconfig` - this returns the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Which is weird, because I'm pretty sure the fan works. I can hear it running, just not very loud.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Toshiba Satellite Radius, which was originally loaded with Windows 8.

Comment: Sudden overheating problems might be caused by dust buildup or even some other blockage (like a piece of tape came lose and now blocks things).  Did you check for that?

Comment: I did open up the laptop and vacuum out the vents and fan, but that didn't seem to do much. That said, I do live with pets so I'm not ruling that out. What would be the best way to clean it?

Comment: pwmconfig is for 4 pin PWM fans, usually found on desktops.

Comment: @rtaft What would I use for laptop fans?

Comment: If it was me I would be taking it for repair.

Comment: @computer_hoarder `thinkfan` seems to work well with IBM/Lenovo.  `i8kfan` works well with Dells.  Not sure what would work with Toshibas